# R markdown inline r printing a list

Tags: r, markdown, inline

I am trying to figure out if I can write a list inline in Markdown. It may not be possible.  This is the script I am trying out.  It does not produce any output.  Any ideas?

```
/*.Rmd script */
---
title: "Markdown list test"
author: "Richard Wilson"
date: "27/07/2020"
output: html_document /*output format */
---
```

I have just set up a simple list and loop function in a chunk to ensure code works - which it does

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(lubridate)
```

```{r, echo =FALSE}
emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary")

for (j in seq_along(emp_name))
     {
       print(paste0(j,': ',emp_name[j],', '))
       }
```
````

This is the section that does not do anything. I want it to say "Today (date) Rick, Dan ,Michelle, Ryan, Gary, are of sick."

```
Today (`r lubridate::today()`) 

`r for (j in seq_along(emp_name))
     {
       print(paste0(j,': ',emp_name[j],', '))
       } `  are of sick.
```

Comment: I would recommend putting complex code in chunks and then printing the output in inline code. Here `paste(unlist(emp_name), sep = ', ')` should simplify the code - even better options in `glue` package

Comment: Yes just seen an example by Thomas Mock, that shows a glue example.  Thanks for the point towards glue